# DateFormat Error

Tags: android, date-format

Under new Date(); it has an error. I want to place it as a file name.

Date date = new Date();

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmSS");
filename = dateFormat.format(date).concat(".jpg");

Comment: *Always* post the error message if you want people to solve that error for you. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for more ideas about how to ask questions well.

Comment: Uppercase "S" is for milliseconds. Are you sure you want this ? If you want seconds use lowercase "s"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that the following code will work fine.I tested it has no error.
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmSS");
String filename = dateFormat.format(date).concat(".jpg");